# Anticommutator of gauge covariant derivatives

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, gauge-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, anticommutator

I must convert some dimension-6 operators I've obtained to the SILH base (ref: [this](https://indico.cern.ch/event/351209/contributions/1758357/attachments/694267/953322/contino_LHCXSWG2.pdf), "Review of the SILH basis", CERN presentation by R. Contino).
In this conversion I've got operators such as $D_{\mu}D_{\nu}H^{\dagger} D^{\nu}D^{\mu}H = \frac{1}{4}(G'_{\mu\nu}H^{\dagger} G^{\prime\nu\mu}H + \{D_{\mu},D_{\nu}\} H^{\dagger} \{D_{\nu},D_{\mu}\}H)$.
In the SILH base I should have only operators of the kind $DG DH^{\dagger} H, GGH ^{\dagger} H $, i.e. no second covariant derivatives on the Higgs doublet.
However, I'm having problems in re-writing $\{D_{\mu}, D_{\nu}\}H$. What is this anticommutator equivalent to?
I'm not finding anything in literature, and opening this derivative explicitely breaks the covariance of the operator.

(Note: $G' = \frac{g^*}{i}G$)

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: I’m guessing you writing out terms in the sense of EFTs. You can then integrate the derivative by parts and use D^2 H = 0.

Comment: Hi Prahar, thanks for the suggestion. In the end it's what I've done, now I've solved the problem.

Comment: @Lenz Could you please share your calculation? I have been trying for so long. I could not do it.